# Use memcache for different domains (the same keys) on one server

Tags: php, codeigniter, memcached

I have this situation:
I have 2 sites on one server - and I use the same frameworks (based on Codeigniter framework). And in this code I use memcache like

```
    $memcache = new Memcache;
    $memcache->connect('localhost', 11211);
    $value = $memcache->set('max_id', 100500);
```

And in this case when I change this value on site1 I also have this value for site2, but I need different values for different sites.

Off course I can replace all keys, adding site_url() like so:

```
$value = $memcache->set(base_url() . 'max_id', 100500);
```

But maybe exist better solution ?

Comment: I have always used your suggested solution of prepending a unique value on my keys. In my experience it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that solution:
Create new class, which inherited from Memcache and use on my sites this class.

```
class Site_Memcache extends Memcache
{
    private $_prefix = '';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_prefix = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    }

    public function set($key, $var, $flag = null, $expire = null)
    {
        parent::set($this->_prefix . $key, $var, $flag, $expire);
    }

    public function get($key, &$flags = null)
    {
        return parent::get($this->_prefix . $key, $flags);
    }

    public function delete($key)
    {
        return parent::delete($this->_prefix . $key);
    }
}
```